# Use HTTP CONNECT instead of HTTP GET

Tags: python, python-requests, locust

Is it possible with locust create following message for the proxy ( https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-30 ):

```
CONNECT server.example.com:80 HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com:80
Proxy-Authorization: basic aGVsbG86d29ybGQ=
```

Now locust generates following:

```
GET server.example.com:80 HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com:80
Proxy-Authorization: basic aGVsbG86d29ybGQ=
```

My proxy server does not work with the last one and connection to end point http-server is impossible.

Enabling proxy usage for locust is easy but it uses protocol where CONNECT is missing

Answer (score 1):

Locust ignores proxy settings by default, but you can enable it by setting

```
self.client.trust_env = True
```

(then you just make whatever request you would normally do)

See https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html?highlight=proxy#http-proxy-settings

Comment: I added last sentence to question. Usage is not problem but it produces "not compliant" message for the proxy. Yes this is arguable thing I suppose

Comment: Aha... hmm. I havent encountered this issue myself, so I dont know. But perhaps try googling to see if someone has had the problem using just the requests lib?

Comment: What I've understood is that requests does CONNECT sending for https connections, but my strict proxy is waiting that also for ordinary http connection.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I guess my answer wasnt of much help then.. maybe the requests documentation about proxies can help https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/